# python Multiprocessing Bottleneck

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python code that initially uses sklearn lib to train a KNN classifier which produces two python objects: model and vectorizer. These two objects will next be used to classify (categorize) my data.

Next, I have a very large dataframe with the following two columns (among many other columns):

category : this column will contain the output of the classifier above

data_path : this column is the path to a data file containing the input to the classifier above

First, I used the df.apply method as below to process the dataframe:

```
def get_classifier_result(row, model, vectorizer):
    with open(row['data_path'], "r") as f:
        my_txt = f.readlines()
    ### run the classifier and classify my_txt input here and generate category value
    row['category'] = category

df = pd.read_csv(my_df, sep='\t', header=0)
df.apply(lambda row: get_classifier_result(row, model, vectorizer), axis=1)
```

This code took over 24 hours to run on a beefy Linux box server with 56 cores. So I tried to use the multiprocessing to speed things up:

```
import multiprocessing

def get_classifier_result(row, model, vectorizer):
    with open(row['data_path'], "r") as f:
        my_txt = f.readlines()
    ### run the classifier and classify my_txt input here and generate category value
    row['category'] = category

df = pd.read_csv(my_df, sep='\t', header=0)
p = multiprocessing.Pool(int(40))
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    p.apply_async(get_classifier_result, [row, model, vectorizer])
```

This approach does not give any improvement. Displaying htop on the linux box reveals that all 40 processes are in S (sleep) mode except one. So I am essentially running only one process as I was in the df.apply approach.

The problem seems to be related to the size of model and vectorizer objects. If I train the classifier with a smaller training dataset so that model and vectorizer objects are reduced in size (let say by a factor of 20), then htop shows all 40 processes in ready mode and running and things really speed up. I tried to use the Manager() and pass these two objects in a shared list to the processes with no avail:

```
m = Manager()
my_list = [model,vectorizer]
my_shared_list = m.list(my_list)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    p.apply_async(get_classifier_result, [row, my_shared_list])
```

I even tried to run with only 3 processes in the pool, but the result is the same (only one process is alive while the other two are in sleep mode).

Why would all processes except only one be in sleep mode and waiting. How would one find out what are they waiting for? And why reducing the size of parameter objects to the spawn processes avoid this issue?